# How can i setup onItemClickListner on Custom ListView Feed using Volley?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, android-volley, custom-lists

I'm making this custom list view in android using volley, but I'm unable to setup onItemClickListner, here's my code.

MainActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.data.FeedItem;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://1001.herobo.com/test.php";
    public List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        //final FeedListAdapter find = new FeedListAdapter(null, feedItems);
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A0D468")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String item = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }



    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

FeedListAdapter.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter;

import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.R;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.data.FeedItem;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

FeedItem.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed.data;

public class FeedItem {
    private int id;
    private String name, status, image, profilePic, timeStamp, url;

    public FeedItem() {
    }

    public FeedItem(int id, String name, String image, String status,
            String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImge() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImge(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

FeedImageView.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener;

public class FeedImageView extends ImageView {

    public interface ResponseObserver {
        public void onError();

        public void onSuccess();
    }

    private ResponseObserver mObserver;

    public void setResponseObserver(ResponseObserver observer) {
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    /**
     * The URL of the network image to load
     */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network
     * image is loaded.
     */
    private int mDefaultImageId;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
     */
    private int mErrorImageId;

    /**
     * Local copy of the ImageLoader.
     */
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    /**
     * Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished)
     */
    private ImageContainer mImageContainer;

    public FeedImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that
     * calling this will immediately either set the cached image (if available)
     * or the default image specified by
     * {@link VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
     * 
     * NOTE: If applicable, {@link VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)}
     * and {@link VolleyImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called
     * prior to calling this function.
     * 
     * @param url
     *            The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
     * @param imageLoader
     *            ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the
     * attempt to load it completes.
     */
    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event
     * that the image requested fails to load.
     */
    public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
        mErrorImageId = errorImage;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
     * 
     * @param isInLayoutPass
     *            True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
     */
    private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        boolean isFullyWrapContent = getLayoutParams() != null
                && getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                && getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a
        // wrap-content/wrap-content
        // view, hold off on loading the image.
        if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
            return;
        }

        // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old
        // requests and clear the
        // currently loaded image.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
            if (mImageContainer != null) {
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                mImageContainer = null;
            }
            setDefaultImageOrNull();
            return;
        }

        // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be
        // canceled.
        if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
            if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
                // if the request is from the same URL, return.
                return;
            } else {
                // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's
                // fetching a different URL.
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                setDefaultImageOrNull();
            }
        }

        // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL.
        // Load the new image
        // from the network.
        ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                        }

                        if (mObserver != null) {
                            mObserver.onError();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response,
                            boolean isImmediate) {
                        // If this was an immediate response that was delivered
                        // inside of a layout
                        // pass do not set the image immediately as it will
                        // trigger a requestLayout
                        // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image
                        // by posting back to
                        // the main thread.
                        if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                            post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    onResponse(response, false);
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        int bWidth = 0, bHeight = 0;
                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {

                            setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                            bWidth = response.getBitmap().getWidth();
                            bHeight = response.getBitmap().getHeight();
                            adjustImageAspect(bWidth, bHeight);

                        } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                        }

                        if (mObserver != null) {
                            mObserver.onSuccess();

                        }
                    }
                });

        // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
        mImageContainer = newContainer;

    }

    private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
        if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
        } else {
            setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        loadImageIfNecessary(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
            // out the image from the view.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setImageBitmap(null);
            // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if
            // necessary.
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    /*
     * Adjusting imageview height
     * */
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int swidth = getWidth();
        int new_height = 0;
        new_height = swidth * bHeight / bWidth;
        params.width = swidth;
        params.height = new_height;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

AppController.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app;

import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.volley.LruBitmapCache;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

LruBitmapCache.java

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed.volley;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extends from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`
and overrides `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id)` instead of `setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: when try to extend it to ListActivity the app stops, is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: should i post my log?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.listviewfeed/info.androidhive.listviewfeed.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: it has: 

<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:divider="@null" android:id="@+id/list"/>

Comment: Remove the listView reference and put setListAdapter(adapter)

Comment: Change android:id="@+id/list" to android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: when i do that findViewById wont find my list view

Comment: You dont need to find your listview, remove that reference and call setListAdapter(listAdapter) onCreate

Comment: the errors gone and the app loads, but it still wont do anything on click:

`protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+feedItems.get(+position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  
  
 }`

Comment: try: Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked at "+ ((FeedListAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: no luck, i dont think its taking the click, i also tried starting another activity on click.. nothing happened